# Plotly - Animate Scatter3d with fixed Mesh3d with slider

Tags: python, plotly

Hi I am struggling on trying to get the animation slider to work. Basically, my goal is to develop an animation of two UAVs (with given x,y,z coordinates over time) over a fixed mesh. The animation runs if I press the play button, but the slider isn't updated. The animation also takes to much time to run. Is there a way to reduce the rendering time?  (The mesh is quite big so I didn't upload it completely)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#UAV 1 and UAV 2 coordinates for 6 frames
xx = [[623948.6134,628948.6134],[624948.6134,627948.6134],[625948.6134,626948.6134],[626948.6134,625948.6134],[627948.6134,624948.6134],[628948.6134,623948.6134]]
yy = [[4457407.483,4457407.483],[4457407.483,4457407.483],[4457407.483,4457407.483],[4457407.483,4457407.483],[4457407.483,4457407.483],[4457407.483,4457407.483]]
zz = [[1505,1052.746554],[1496.746554,1056],[1278.690351,1093],[1093,1278.690351],[1056,1496.746554],[1052.746554,1505]]

mesh3d_map = go.Mesh3d(
dict(x = [623948.625 ...],
y = [4462839.5,...],
z = [1400,...],
intensity = [1400,...],
name = 'Terrain',
showlegend = True,
colorscale = 'Viridis',
showscale = False,
opacity = 1,
flatshading = False,
visible = True,
hoverinfo = 'skip')


initUAVData = go.Scatter3d(
                x=xx[0],
                y=yy[0],
                z=zz[0],
                name=f'str(0)',
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(
                    color='Green',
                    size=12  
                )
)

fig = go.Figure(
            data=[mesh3d_map,initUAVData]
        )

#Frames generation
frames = []
for i in range(6):
            
            scatter = go.Scatter3d(
                x=xx[i],
                y=yy[i],
                z=zz[i],
                name=f'str(i)',
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(
                    color='Green',
                    size=12  
                ),
            )
            frame = go.Frame(data=[scatter], traces=[1])
            frames.append(frame)
            
            
#Assign frames to fig
fig.frames = frames
#Fig layout config
fig.layout = go.Layout(
font = dict(size = 13, family = 'Open Sans'), 
title = dict(x = 0.45, text = '3D Dubins Path Optimisation'), 
width = 1300, 
height = 650, 
margin = dict(b = 50, l = 50, r = 50, t = 50, pad = 0), 
modebar = dict(orientation = 'h'), 
autosize = True, 
showlegend = True, 
legend = dict( 
x = 1.16, 
y = 0.5, 
valign = 'middle', 
xanchor = 'center', 
yanchor = 'middle', 
borderwidth = 1, 
orientation = 'v'), 
scene = dict( 
aspectmode='data',
#X Axis 
xaxis = dict( 
type = 'linear', 
dtick = 500, 
range = [623405, 629923], 
tick0 = 0, 
title = dict(text = 'x_[m]'), 
showgrid = True, 
showline = True, 
tickmode = 'linear', 
zeroline = True, 
autorange = False, 
gridwidth = 5, 
tickangle = 45, 
tickprefix = '', 
ticksuffix = '', 
showticklabels = True, 
backgroundcolor = '#eefbff'), 
#Y Axis 
yaxis = dict( 
type = 'linear', 
dtick = 500, 
range = [4456864, 4463382], 
tick0 = 0, 
title = dict(text = 'y_[m]'), 
showgrid = True, 
showline = True, 
tickmode = 'linear', 
zeroline = True, 
autorange = False, 
gridwidth = 5, 
tickangle = 45, 
tickprefix = '', 
ticksuffix = '', 
showticklabels = True, 
backgroundcolor = '#eefbff'), 
#Z Axis 
zaxis = dict( 
type = 'linear', 
dtick = 100, 
range = [332, 2134], 
tick0 = 0, 
title = dict(text = 'z_[m]'), 
showgrid = True, 
showline = True, 
tickmode = 'linear', 
zeroline = True, 
autorange = False, 
gridwidth = 5, 
tickangle = 0, 
tickprefix = '', 
ticksuffix = '', 
showticklabels = True, 
backgroundcolor = '#eefbff'), 
#Camera 
camera = dict( 
up = dict(x = 0, y = 0, z = 1), 
eye = dict(x = 1.25, y = 1.25, z = 1.25), 
center = dict(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0), 
projection = dict(type = 'perspective')), 
aspectratio = dict(x = 3, y = 3, z = 3)),
#Add play button
updatemenus=[
                dict(
                    type="buttons",
                    buttons=[
                        dict(
                            label="Play",
                            method="animate",
                            args=[None]
                            
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]


)


#Slider generation
sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Frame:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}


for j in range(6):
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [f'str(j)'],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': True},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': str(j),
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)
#Assign slider to fig  
fig['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

fig.show()
'''
```